# Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values with websockets in node

Tags: node.js, sockets

The error I am getting when on connection is:

"Failed to load http://localhost:8081/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MLlqN2Y: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:3000, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access."

I saw similar issues around here, but attempted all of the solutions with no avail.  Here is my server code atm:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
var Models = require('./models');
//var authRoutes = require('./routes/auth.js');
var apiRoutes = require('./routes/api.js');
var http = require('http');



app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
//
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

 server.listen(8081);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('connected to socket')
  socket.emit('connect', {hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('cmd', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
  socket.on('room', function(data) {
    socket.broadcast.to(data.doc).emit('joined', data.user);
    socket.join(data.doc);

  });

});

app.set('port', 8080);

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${app.get('port')}`)
})
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm facing the same issue!

Comment: i also facing the same issue anyone have answer???